# Как ghci запускает функции?

Tags: haskell

Я пришел с C#, где есть функция Main, которая является entry point. В новых версиях можно Main не писать, он подставляется [автоматически](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements)

Теперь к хаскелю, тут тоже есть main, который выполняет точно такую же функцию. Если запускать через ghc, то будет вызываться main, но в хаскеле есть еще ghci, который позволяет вызывать напрямую функции.

например, `ghci anotherF` вызывает функцию `anotherF`. Мне немного непонятно, как происходит такая компиляция без вызова main. Или main все-таки вызывается, но неявно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bash
$ ghci anotherF
```

загружает исходный файл `anotherF.hs`, компилирует его, и, не выполняя никаких дальнейших действий, ждет пользовательского ввода. Функция `main` не вызывается, и может отсутствовать в таком файле совсем. Значения переменных остаются невычисленными, пока не будут запрошены пользователем.

ghci в отличие от компилятора ghc - интерактивная среда, которая позволяет "пощупать" переменные и поприменять функции (по умолчанию в режиме интерпретации) из исходного файла, не запуская его на выполнение.

Что-то похожее есть в интерпретаторе python с ключом `-i`, но в отличие от python, где каждая строчка программы - инструкция, и должна быть выполнена перед тем как управление передастся пользователю, в Haskell - это список определений, которые становятся важны только когда к ним обращаются.